# How to initialize form as scope variable in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a simple angular form

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="myFormController"></form>
```

and need to call `$setPristine()` to `myForm` in `myFormController`. What is the best way to initialize this form as a `$scope` variable?

I tried `$scope.myForm.$setPristine();` but it gave me:

> Cannot read property '$setPristine' of undefined

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT** From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form):

> *name* (optional) 
>   Name of the form. If specified, the form controller will be published into related scope, under this name.

That means you can access it in a controller, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form` directive does publish the name of the form to the scope. But if the form is nested inside the `ng-controller` element, then the form's scope variable is not **yet** available when the controller function runs.

As an illustration:

```
<div ng-controller="OuterCtrl">
  <form name="form1">
    <div ng-controller="InnerCtrl"></div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The following would happen:

```
.controller("OuterCtrl", function($scope){
   // $scope.form1.$setPristine(); // this will fail
})
.controller("InnerCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.form1.$setPristine(); // this will succeed
});
```

It is rarely needed to access the form when the controller function runs. Typically, it's done in response to some action, like a submit action. When that happens, the `"OuterCtrl"` will have `$scope.form1`:

```
.controller("OuterCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.submitForm = function(){
      //... do something with form data
      $scope.form1.$setPristine();
   }
});
```

In that respect, `$timeout` would, in fact, work and would not cause race conditions. But you should re-examine *why* you need it the form when the controller function first runs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your controller.

```
$timeout(function () {
   // here you should be able to access $scope.myForm
})
```

Comment: apart from not working in this case `$timeout` is never a good solution ;)

Comment: It worked for me. Can you please create a plunker/fiddle for this.

Comment: `ngController` will processed at `priority:500`, after which `ngInit` with `priority:450`, then `form` directive with the `default priority`, `$timeout` will guarantee the successful compilation of `formDirective`.

Comment: @DonJuwe, did this work for you? or did you found any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

I just wasted some time dealing with this. In my case, I had the form shown a bit later using a `ng-if`. Changing the form conditions to an `ng-show` resolved the non-initialization of the `$scope.myform`.

Comment: I have the feeling I ran into similar issues before. But darn, yet again I fall into it.